# KivyMD: Change font_name of MDLabel

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I would like to change font_name property of MDLabel. But I want to add this component dynamically, in `.py` file, not `.kv`.

So when I write something like this:

#### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

class MainApp(MDApp):    
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        otherLabel = MDLabel(
                text="one more text",
                halign="center",
                font_name="18328",
                font_size="50sp"
            )
        screen.add_widget(
            otherLabel
        )
        return screen

MainApp().run()
```

it does not help. How can I implement font applying dynamically?

#### KV string

```
KV = '''
Screen:    
    MDCard:
        id: box
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: "8dp"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "280dp", "180dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        
        MDLabel:
            text: "Hello"
            theme_text_color: "Secondary"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            font_name: '18328.ttf'    

            
        MDSeparator:
            height: "1dp"
            
        MDLabel:
            text: "Body"
        
        MDLabel:
            text: "Hello"
            font_name: 'BebasNeue-Regular.otf'
            font_size: "50sp"
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a reference in the screen itself (also you don't need to use .ttf, the library adds it automatically, just the filename without extension is fine)

```py
class MyScreen(Screen):
    my_MD_Label = None

    def on_kv_post(self, instance):
        self.my_MD_Label = MDLabel(
            text="one more text"
            font_name="18328"
        )
        self.ids.box.add_widget(self.my_MD_Label)
```

And whenever you want to change it, you can simply do this

```py
self.my_MD_Label.font_name = "new_font"  # When in same screen
self.manager.get_screen('MyScreen').my_MD_Label.font_name = "new_font"  #When in other screen
```

Comment: where can I initialize this screen, if I have got the code that I've just updated

Comment: Initialize the screen in the python file, like I showed, and use `<MyScreen>:` in kv instead of `Screen:` and give name also 'MyScreen' in .kv, then  add the class in the build

Comment: Like this in kv `<MyScreen>:`, next line, `name: 'MyScreen'`, and in python's build method, create a ScreenManager, then add an instance of the MyScreen to it, then return the screenmanager, like this `sm = ScreenManager()``sm.add_widget(MyScreen())``return sm`, that's all the code there should be in build

Comment: when does the ```on_kv_post``` should work? I start the program, but no widgets have appeared

Comment: Can you update the code, there might be something you missed, `on_kv_post` is fired after it's widget's creation

Comment: Oh you are almost done, you just need to add the MDLabel to the Screen, add to the end of on_kv_post: `self.add_widget(self.my_MD_Label)`

Comment: thank you so much. Where I can read about ```on_kv_post``` method?

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=kivy%20widget#module-kivy.uix.widget, its there in the API section, if this answer helped you, consider marking it correct, glad to help

Comment: sure, but 1 more question, how can I place a custom polygon at the background of the screen using kivymd?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227147/discussion-between-yash-kolekar-and-yaroslav-hladkyi).